# Arranging multiple objects in a circle QML

Tags: qt, qml

I need to arrange multiple qtquick objects (circle shapes) such that they themselves form a circle. I can't find a way of creating objects en-masse such that their properties are accessible post-creation. At the moment I'm creating three different objects in a JS for loop: circles, rotations, and translations. Then I'm setting the rotations and translation as the transform component of each circle before their temporary variables (within the for loop) go out of scope. But I'd like to be able to change the transform component of each circle at any time. Is there a way to do this?

Here's my JS code:

```
function drawCircles() {
var translationcomponent = Qt.createComponent("translations.qml");
var circlecomponent = Qt.createComponent("circles.qml");
var rotationcomponent = Qt.createComponent("rotations.qml");
for(var i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    var circle = circlecomponent.createObject(appbase);
    var translation = translationcomponent.createObject(appbase);
    var rotation = rotationcomponent.createObject(appbase);

    rotation.angle = 72*i;
    rotation.origin.x = 25;
    rotation.origin.y = 25;
    translation.y = -150
    circle.transform = [translation,rotation];

}
```

My main qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import "drawcircles.js" as Dcop

Rectangle {
property int originx: qmlwidth/2
property int originy: qmlheight/2
id: appbase
height: qmlheight
width: qmlwidth
color: "green"

Component.onCompleted: Dcop.drawCircles();

// below here unimportant
Rectangle {
    height: 50
    width: height
    color: "red"
    radius: width/2
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

}

Text {
    id: qmlw
    text: appbase.width
}

Text {
    anchors.left: qmlw.right
    text: appbase.height

}

}
```

Here's what the application looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first idea is to use [PathView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-pathview.html) to arrange the items, and one of [Path](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-path.html#details) segments for example [PathSvg](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-pathsvg.html):

```js
PathView {
    width: 400
    height: 400
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement { name: "element1" }
        ListElement { name: "element2" }
        ListElement { name: "element3" }
        ListElement { name: "element4" }
        ListElement { name: "element5" }
        ListElement { name: "element6" }
        ListElement { name: "element7" }
        ListElement { name: "element8" }
    }
    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: 40
        height: 40
        radius: 20
        color: "blue"
        Text {
            text: name
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            transform: [
                Translate {y: -30}
            ]
        }
    }
    path: Path {
        id: myPath
        startX: 0; startY: 0
        PathSvg { path: "M 200 200 m -200 0 a 200 200 0 1 0 400 0 a 200 200 0 1 0 -400 0" }
    }
}
```

`path` is hardcoded here, but you can adopt it according to the next:

`M cx cy m -r, 0 a r,r 0 1,0 (r * 2),0 a r,r 0 1,0 -(r * 2),0`

where `r` is te radius of the circle, (`cx`, `cy`) - is the center.

The same way but more clear:

```
path: Path {
        startX: 200
        startY: 0
        PathArc { x: 200; y: 400; radiusX: 200; radiusY: 200; useLargeArc: true }
        PathArc { x: 200; y: 0; radiusX: 200; radiusY: 200; useLargeArc: true }
    }
```

The problem is that you cannot paint fill circle because in this case start point = end point end nothing will be drawn. The workaround is to use 2 semicircles.