# Holding common objects as a list in QML

Tags: qt, architecture, qml

I am having an architectural problem in the app I am developing in QML. Please consider the following figure:

[image]

Some facts about the application:

1. I need to store an array of elements names, here it is Orange, Apple and Banana.
2. The amount of elements is fixed and will not change at runtime.
3. Although there are only 1 array of elements, it should be possible to present the in different graphical forms at the same time. In the example, the elements are once represented as yellow squares, and other time as green triangles. They do not necessarily have to be shown in the same order. But the order also doesn't change at runtime.

I want to avoid unnecessary code copying, thus, wanted to use only 1 list with different graphical representations. I am having problems implementing this however.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for answer. The problem is, I have no MWE, since the things I tried will not even run. This is more of a concept questions, since I am not sure how to write the code (thus no MWE provided). Instead, I introduced a concept using an image.

Comment: It also only shows the idea expressed with QML components, not to be interpreted as working code, since it does not work like I stated. I used it to help understanding my question. I can remove this part if you think its contradictory.

Comment: Its shows that the code does not work the way I showed it. The formatting is wrong, yes. Will fix,.

Comment: Architectural problem but QML specific, since I dont know how to do it with QML in practice.

Comment: I have removed the code part.

Comment: Okay, now if we go to the central point, all the points that point to refer to a model, a model can be adapted to different views.

Comment: I'm agree with @eyllanesc, your question clearly describes the classic model, in terms of MVC of course.

Comment: What will determine the position of the objects?

Comment: Thanks for answer. The position of the objects will either be distributed in a row or a column. There should also be a possibility to set position and rotation for each item manually (thats why I have drawn the blocks this way. there should be the possibility to use this without any visual placement pattern). I am aware of the concept of the presenter and model I just dont know how to do it in QML. I would appreciate an example in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand what OP wants to archive, but I guess that model is what you need.
This is a simple example of reusable model:

```
import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 400
    title: qsTr("Model example")

    ListModel {
        id:  myModel;
        ListElement { name: "Apple" }
        ListElement { name: "Orange" }
        ListElement { name: "Banana" }
    }

    Repeater {
        model: myModel
        delegate: type1
    }

    Repeater {
        model: myModel
        delegate: type2
    }

    ListView {
        model: myModel
        delegate: Text { text: name; height: 30; }
        width: 100
        height: 200
    }

    ComboBox {
        width: 100
        y: 200
        model: myModel
    }

    Component {
        id: type1
        Canvas {
            x: 100 + Math.round(Math.random() * 400)
            y: Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
            rotation: Math.round(Math.random() * 360)
            antialiasing: true
            width: 100
            height: 100
            onPaint: {
                var ctx = getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle = "#00DD00";
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(50, 0);
                ctx.lineTo(100, 100);
                ctx.lineTo(0, 100);
                ctx.fill();
            }
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: name
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: type2
        Rectangle {
            x: 100 + Math.round(Math.random() * 400)
            y: 200 + Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
            rotation: Math.round(Math.random() * 360)
            antialiasing: true
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: "orange"
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant. I know how the theoretical classical model should look like in general, but I did not know how to implement it using QML. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, can't comment until I have enough reputation, but can't you just use [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html) for this? Then you could use two path views that determine where the objects go. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123705/arranging-multiple-objects-in-a-circle-qml), but you would have your own QAbstractListModel instead of the examples ListModel. The delegate would determine the shape of the items.

The reason to use QAbstractListModel over QML's ListModel is because ListModel is created runtime.

Comment: Using `ListModel` or even a plain js array as a model is fine here. It all depends on OP's needs.

Comment: Generally speaking, I would like to keep the QML as separate as possible from the C++ code. If its only possible, I would stick to the QML only method.