# Qt/QML: How to add elements to ListModel with Repeater

Tags: qt, qml

I want to have some elements arranged in a circle similar to how it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45126243/19264919)

However, I want to add a lot of elements (somewhere between 100 and 200) and I don't want to specify each item manually. Also, I want each element to have a different color, based on the order in the view. A Repeater would be ideal because I can also use the *[index](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-repeater.html#:%7E:text=Delegates%20are%20exposed%20to%20a%20read%2Donly%20index%20property%20that%20indicates%20the%20index%20of%20the%20delegate%20within%20the%20repeater.%20For%20example%2C%20the%20following%20Text%20delegate%20displays%20the%20index%20of%20each%20repeated%20item%3A)* property of its items to control the color.

Here I declare each element manually:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    PathView {
        width: 400
        height: 400
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        model: ListModel {
            id: modelelements
            ListElement{required property int index}
            ListElement{required property int index}
            ListElement{required property int index}
            ListElement{required property int index}
            ListElement{required property int index}
            ListElement{required property int index}
            ListElement{required property int index}
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 40
            height: 40
            radius: 20
            color: Qt.rgba(0,index/modelelements.count,0,1)
        }
        path: Path {
            id: myPath
            startX: 0; startY: 0
            PathSvg { path: "M 200 200 m -200 0 a 200 200 0 1 0 400 0 a 200 200 0 1 0 -400 0" }
        }
    }
}
```

and this works. The result looks like this:

[image]

But I don't know how to use a Repeater to add the items. When I try this:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")


    PathView {
        width: 400
        height: 400
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        model: ListModel {
            id: modelelements
            Repeater{
                model: 7
                ListElement{
                    required property int index
                }
            }
        }
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 40
            height: 40
            radius: 20
            color: Qt.rgba(0,index/modelelements.count,0,1)
        }
        path: Path {
            id: myPath
            startX: 0; startY: 0
            PathSvg { path: "M 200 200 m -200 0 a 200 200 0 1 0 400 0 a 200 200 0 1 0 -400 0" }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error at runtime:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/test/Main.qml:17:13: ListElement: cannot contain nested elements
```

I tried to find a solution for this but I haven't found anything. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you specify your final purpose? I believe there should be a simpler way to implement what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Just tested on Qt 5.15

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    PathView {
        id: pw
        width: 400
        height: 400
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        model: 25
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 40
            height: 40
            radius: 20
            color: Qt.rgba(0, model.index/pw.model, 0, 1)
        }
        path: Path {
            id: myPath
            startX: 0; startY: 0
            PathSvg { path: "M 200 200 m -200 0 a 200 200 0 1 0 400 0 a 200 200 0 1 0 -400 0" }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: pw.model++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Mike pointed out, your `Repeater` `model` can be simply an integer.

Since your `PathView` just follows a circle, you can achieve a similar effect if you just make use of the `rotation` property provided you set an appropriate origin.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    property int total: Math.floor(slider.value)
    Repeater {
        model: total
        Item {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            rotation: 360 * index / total
            Rectangle {
                x: 200; width: 40; height: 40; radius: 20
                color: Qt.rgba(0,index/total,0,1)
            }
        }
    }
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        Label { Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter; text: total }
        Slider { id: slider; from: 5; to: 50 }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACRXichZHNbsIwDMfvfQofx4RK93kIp4nLkJg0ticIrWmjpXHluhsI8e5zU4QoO8yHxE78s/9xXN0QC6xl3bn8K3GjMF1QECbfXp+v7J46aZN3WyIcElBrmBpk2YMLAkJivYE3K1W69UR803pXIKff1nc4icAHNmgF+cT3VlOBikX6fLgUrC9yerMhr4jbNMegBZbBQGNZ/VESaxVxpJcPzxncqq4CdzC7qj4oycWG0uNVm952Bu6zbA4/rpDKwKO6FbqyksFnW7iu7XP+kDl5YqMjS7nc2JtsGgXMYvtpNr2bjIhjMvaGdUG+q8Mw7Qtx/75/ZTfo4QADmVrvylBrQpTz0kevi8jOQXAnp5FfiPiM36UVXGFg+Ls5bJlqA0/KkG7ZWenxF1vMpm8=)